# Adding custom class before old classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have to add class before already added classes. E.g.

```
<a class="old_class another_class"/>
```

Now I'm adding class by **jQuery.addClass()**

```
<a class="old_class another_class justAdded_class"/>
```

And this is wrong order. I need this in that order:

```
<a class="justAdded_class old_class another_class"/>
```

How can I do this? If you wanna, I can paste here my jQuery code to adding/removing classes by button.

Comment: I am more curious as to why you need the classes to come in a specific order. Maybe your actual problem can be solved in another, better way?

Comment: For what reason on this planet you need a class to be before the other ones? Do you need to access such data later or what?

Comment: ⇑⇑⇑ is that because some specific CSS rules?

Comment: Overly specific CSS rules I guess!

Comment: [link](http://helpdesk.uni.lodz.pl/) I don't know. Just point at menu, then right click on submenu.
When submenu appears, javscript has add some classes and '-enabled' and then my class is adding, that -enabled is pasting to wrong class. I don't know why someone use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
 var oldClass = $(this).attr('class');
 $('a').attr('class', '').addClass('justAdded_class ' + oldClass);
```

Comment: console.log(oldClass) returns 'undefined'. Do you wanna my jQuery code?

Comment: Url: https://jsfiddle.net/x0fev1yq/
I have too much files. This is basically a widget for wordpres...

Comment: I have updated your js in jsfiddle. if it it not working again, then you have to call the addClass function separately once all the data is loaded in the page. it may be showing undefined because you may be checking for class name before data is loaded.

Comment: Still that class is adding at the end of class attr.

Comment: That  `.attr('class', '')` kills my page.

Comment: OK, then please add HTML, JQuery and CSS and reproduce same working in jsfiddle.net/x0fev1yq and updated me, then I may be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : read existing class and then prepend the new class to it. And then set class attribute with new value.

```
var classList = $('a.old_class.another_class').attr('class');

classList = 'just_added_class ' + classList;

$('a.old_class.another_class').attr('class',classList);
```

Comment: As per your selector, new class will be applied for all the anchor tags in the DOM

Comment: OP does not provide a special conditon thats why I took `$('a')`, as per requirement OP can modify the selector.

Comment: Be aware than `attr()` getter will return only for first matched element in set. I guess it isn't an issue here but could be

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar He did: `Adding custom class before old classes` so sounds like: `old_class another_class`